# Numbers getting appended instead of getting added to an int variable while doing file operations in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, append

I am trying to store employee ids and number of files done by them in a text file. And also adding the number of files to a totalFiles variable. But when I output the value of totalFiles, I see all the input appended that i provided to be stored inside the file instead of the addition of the intended values. Why so?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n, i, numFiles;
    char empid[10];
    int totalfiles = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of employees\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("employee.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        return 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("For employee %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("Enter the employee id\n");
        scanf("%s", empid);
        fputs(empid, fp);
        printf("Enter the number of files done\n");
        scanf("%d", &numFiles);
        totalfiles += numFiles;
        fprintf(fp, "%d", numFiles);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Total number of files done by all employees : %d", totalfiles);
}
```

The output that I get is this:

> Enter the number of employees
>   2
>   For employee 1
>   Enter the employee id
>   33
>   Enter the number of files done
>   8
>   For employee 2
>   Enter the employee id
>   20
>   Enter the number of files done
>   6
>   Total number of files done by all employees : 14338206

If you see the output you will notice that the output is nothing but the input I provided just appended next to each other. Please let me know the bug in my code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 14 is the (correct) sum, why the other values are echoed at the end is out of scope of your code. It looks, like your employees.txt is outputted somehow?

Comment: Probably `14` is this code output. `338206` other part read file and output. If the presented code is the actual code, it can not be reproduced.

Comment: that"s what your code is doing - you're printing the **numfiles** into the file for each iteration. Instead, print the totalfiles **after** the loop.

Comment: yeah that's what. what should i do to stop that unneeded output?

Comment: The output of your program doesn't match the program. The program's output on the console is `14` and the contents of the `employe.txt` file is `338206` once the program ha sfinished.

Comment: @Antti Haapala plz edit the code as you suggested. I cannot understand clearly what you meant.

Comment: @Michael Walz how should i stop the contents of file from getting printed?

Comment: @RahulPakhare As I and many others already commented, this is _not_ explainable with what you presented here. Show more of your environment, maybe that will shed some light on it

Comment: @RahulPakhare once again: the output of the program you posted does not match the program you posted. Are you sure the program you are running is the program you have posted?

Comment: Add `\n` to the last printf. Add `return 0;` at the end so as not to confuse the OS. Is this program called from a batch job that next echoes the file?

Comment: yes the rogram is exactly the program i am compiling and running in a linux environment and the output is exactly of the same program

Comment: @RahulPakhare then do what has Paul Oglivie suggested and tell us how the output looks then.

Comment: Please copy paste the command line you use to run the program, verbatim, from the terminal.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie I think that might be reason. I am not running the program on my local machine. Instead, on an online IDE. Maybe they are printing the file contents at the end. But your suggestions provided a readable output. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RahulPakhare I hope you learned at least that when asking a question, you need to provide all details. How could he know that you are running your program on some online IDE (which one BTW)?

Comment: I am really sorry everyone. As you can see from my reputation, I am new to these things. Really apologize for my mistakes. I will keep this in mind next time. And @Michael, the IDE belongs to a pvt ltd company which assesses our code and grades us. So that's kinda private and exclusive for trainees.

Comment: `if (fp == NULL) { printf("Error"); return 0;}` contains a surprisingly large number of issues.  "Error" is not a useful error message. Error messages should be written to stderr, not stdout.  On error, the program should return non-zero.  Replace with `{perror("employee.txt"); return EXIT_FAILURE;}` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your final `printf` statement does not have a newline, its output is not separated from further output. `14` does appear as output, but is immediately followed by some other output, probably the contents of the `employee.txt` file that may be output as part of a command file.

Change your code to output newlines for every piece of information:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n, i, numFiles;
    char empid[10];
    int totalfiles = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of employees\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("employee.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        return 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("For employee %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("Enter the employee id\n");
        if (scanf("%s", empid) != 1)
            return 1;
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", empid);
        printf("Enter the number of files done\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &numFiles) != 1)
            return 1;
        totalfiles += numFiles;
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", numFiles);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Total number of files done by all employees : %d\n", totalfiles);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RahulPakhare: Paul Ogilvie commented with a question about the running environment.  I independently wrote a complete answer with a detailed explanation and a corrected version of your code. Did this answer your question?

Comment: There is nothing really to do after I followed what Paul said. You have told to do the same thing.

Comment: @RahulPakhare: Paul suggested you output a `\n` at the end and add a `return 0;`.  This was the basic problem, and it may have helped you write a quick fix. I also suggest you output a `\n` after each output, which may or may not be useful, and check the return values of the different calls to `scanf()`. Invalid user input in response to the prompts would cause undefined behavior that should be avoided.  If the you run the code in an online test framework, there could be validity tests that it would fail without those checks.  As for most questions, a thorough answer does not fit in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I modified a bit the code to have a better formatted output, you will have in the file "employees.txt" the series "employee id" "num files done"

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
        int n, i, numFiles;
        char empid[10];
        int totalfiles = 0;
        printf("Enter the number of employees\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
            return 1;
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("employee.txt", "w");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Error");
            return 0;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("For employee %d\n", i + 1);
            printf("Enter the employee id\n");
            if (scanf("%s", empid) != 1)
                return 1;
            fprintf(fp, "%s ", empid);
            printf("Enter the number of files done\n");
            if (scanf(" %d", &numFiles) != 1)
                return 1;
            totalfiles += numFiles;
            fprintf(fp, "%d\n", numFiles);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Total number of files done by all employees : %d\n", totalfiles);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: No I want to write the number of files done by each employe into the file and not the total files

Comment: I modified a bit the code to have what you want in a better formatted output